# Convert python while loop to recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

> Herbert attempts to climb the slope (Heffalumps are heavy), so each of
> his rushes gains him only 95% as much distance as his previous rush.
> This means that if his first rush gains him rush_height_gain metres,
> then his second rush will only gain him 0.95 * rush_height_gain
> metres, his third rush 0.95 * 0.95 * rush_height_gain metres, and so
> on. Fortunately, his back sliding reduces in the same way.
>
> The traditional way to write the code is:

```
def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
''' Calculate how many rushes '''
import math    
current_height = 0
rushes = 0
i = 0
while current_height < slope_height:
    current_height += rush_height_gain * (0.95 ** i)
    if current_height < slope_height:
        current_height -= back_sliding * (0.95 ** i)
    rushes += 1
    i += 1
return rushes
```

- ans = num_rushes(10, 10, 9)
  print(ans)  **#result: 1**
- ans = num_rushes(100, 15, 7)
  print(ans) **#result: 19**
- ans = num_rushes(150,20,9)
  print(ans) **#result: 22**

> Now we need to use recursion to improve the efficiency. The recursive
> code I wrote below  didn't get the desired result as above. Please
> point out how to revise it.

```
def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding, current_height=0):


if (slope_height-current_height) < rush_height_gain:
    return 0
else: 
    
    current_height = current_height + 0.95*(rush_height_gain-back_sliding) 
    
    return num_rushes(slope_height, 0.95*rush_height_gain, 0.95*back_sliding, current_height) + 1
```

- ans = num_rushes(10, 10, 9) print(ans)
- ans = num_rushes(100, 15, 7) print(ans)
- ans = num_rushes(150,20,9) print(ans)  **#wrong result - get 23**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive version is doing the backslide *before* checking that the height is reached. This check should happen between the forward rush and the backslide, not after the backslide.

Here is a correction, which also avoids the extra parameter:

```
def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
    if slope_height <= rush_height_gain:
        return int(slope_height > 0)
    return 1 + num_rushes(slope_height - rush_height_gain + back_sliding, 
                          0.95 * rush_height_gain, 0.95 * back_sliding)
```

Note the base case: if the `slope_height` is zero, no step has to be taken and 0 should be returned. In all other cases where the forward rush reaches the height, 1 should be returned.